# List Prime Numbers within a range results in an error message in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am so close to having this cracked, but I cannot see what I'm missing. is-prime? should return true if the number inputted is a prime number or it should return false if the number is not prime. The function I have created works great apart from it will not return false for the number 1. As part of the spec, I was told to set both numbers 1 and 2 which is what I tried doing but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
  (defn is-prime? [n]
  (if (= n 1) false)
  (if (= n 2) no-divisors?)
  (no-divisors? n)
)
```

Here is a list of all the inputs and expected outcomes for is-prime? The only one that returns incorrect is(is-prime? 1).

```
   (is-prime? 1)
=> false
   (is-prime? 2)
=> true
   (is-prime? 3)
=> true
   (is-prime? 4)
=> false
   (is-prime? 101)
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In clojure the result of a function is its last expression, so in your example `(if (= n 1) false)` and `(if (= n 2) no-divisors?)` are always lost, because the last expression is `(no-divisors? n)`.

Try this:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
    (cond 
       (= n 1) false
       (= n 2) true
       :else (no-divisors? n)))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I felt like it was just 1 things that I was missing.

Comment: akond, if you wouldn't mind helping me with another issue. I have a function that is meant to returns the top 10 biggest prime numbers between 2 inputs but it only seems to return nil. This is the code: `(defn print-top-primes [from to]
  (doseq [i (take 10 (reverse (prime-seq from to)))]
    (println i))
  (printf "Total = %d\n" (reduce + (prime-seq from to)))
)`

Comment: What is `prime-seq`?

Comment: sorry. prime-sec prints prime numbers between 2 inputs. `(defn prime-seq [from to]
  (for [i (range from to)
    :let [y (+ i 0)]
    :when (is-prime? i)]
  y))`

Comment: Again, the last expression is `printf`, which always returns `nil`. You have to have something like `(take 10 (reverse (prime-seq from to)))` as the last expression.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'll give it a go. Is there an easy way to make `(take 10 (reverse (prime-seq from to)))` the last expression without breaking everything else and getting errors?

Comment: The easiest way would be to duplicate it in the end. A better way is it to use a local variable.

Comment: I accidentally adding an extra bracket to the end of the code but for some reason this makes the function print. But it only prints the output for that function which I think is not inclusive of the number that starts the range. After the output there is this error: `RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)`

Comment: Make sure you read [range manual](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range). Especially the inclusive/exclusive bits.

Comment: @jordz_dunn, for the future, if you have further questions it is much better to start a new question rather than use the comments section of an existing one. This way other people looking for something similar could find it. Glad you found the solution to your problem!

Comment: @Shlomi sorry I’m new to using StackOverflow. Thank you for letting me know, I’ll create a new question in future.